# Tableview cells from Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, tableview, cell

I have followed this [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/77975/making-a-gesture-driven-to-do-list-app-like-clear-in-swift-part-2). To add a cell to the tableview the code looks like this `toDoItems.append(ToDoItem(text: "CHILDS NAME"))`

This is `toDoItem` :

```
func toDoItemAddedAtIndex(index: Int) {
    let toDoItem = ToDoItem(text: "")
    toDoItems.insert(toDoItem, atIndex: index)
    tableView.reloadData()
    // enter edit mode
    var editCell: TableViewCell
    let visibleCells = tableView.visibleCells as! [TableViewCell]
    for cell in visibleCells {
        if (cell.toDoItem === toDoItem) {
            editCell = cell
            editCell.label.becomeFirstResponder()
            break
        }
    }
}
```

And this is `ToDoItems` :

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
                   cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        cell.selectionStyle = .None
        cell.textLabel?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        let item = toDoItems[indexPath.row]
        //            cell.textLabel?.text = item.text
        cell.delegate = self
        cell.toDoItem = item
        return cell
    }
```

And my `firebase database` looks like this : [image]

JSON :

```
  "Mission-list" : {
    "vJGnbbJX9lbBYwgesjHfNqdzmJs2" : {
    }
  }
```

**Question** : How do I **automatically add a tableview cell** for each child added bellow Mission-list? And set the cells name to the childs name.

Thanks!

Comment: What is *toDoItems*? Give the function to where you are retrieving the data from the Firebase also some relevant code from the *cellForIndexPath*.Also give your JSON structure as text not image, it makes it much easier to navigate...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that **`toDoItem`** is your dataSource variable which carries the data retrieved from Firebase Database. So when you append your data to your Global variable:-

```
toDoItems.append(ToDoItem(text: "CHILDS NAME"))
yourTableView.reloadData()
```